# changing how tasks on a timeline are displayed

Tags: tasks, task-list, timeline

I've been messing around with timelines and I was wondering if anyone has found a way to change how tasks on a timeline are displayed. Some of the things I would like to be able to do:

- Show the timeline callout differently depending on whether or not it is complete (perhaps show completed tasks as grayed-out text or faded or having a strikethrough)
- Showing task callouts as red text if the due date has passed AND the task still has not been marked as incomplete
- Show tasks as orange if the deadline is upcoming (probably by comparing the due date with a second date and changing the color if the difference is greater than a set amount)
- Color coding tasks on a timeline based on the value in a column (such as department or priority).

I also want to be sure that these customizations can also be in effect when showing the timeline rolled up into a Project Summary web part.